# Instal problems , Centos 6, MySql, Tomcat 8

Tags: scadalts

I Have MySql Configured
DB scadabr
user scadabr, pass scadabr

Tomcat8 Running, Examples and Manager all OK

java version "1.7.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.10.1.el6_9-x86_64 u141-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.141-b02, mixed mode)

Scada-LTS.War Download Returns ScadaBR.war file
ScadaBR.War Uploaded to WebApps Folder

Tomcat8 Manager Confirms Running

14-Jul-2017 17:37:04.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 23966 ms
14-Jul-2017 17:38:08.939 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ScadaBR] has started
14-Jul-2017 17:38:10.324 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ScadaBR] is completed

404 Error when opening host:8080/ScadaBR/

Comment: Now is not support for tomcat8, you may use tomcat7 or better use docker scadalts-dev.

Comment: Switched to Tomcat7

Wont even Start

Comment: What error do you get on tomcat 7?